# Apply Expand only to parts of expression

Tags: built-in-symbols

I have the following term:

```
term = (x AngleBracket[x (-x+Sum[v'[y[j]],j])])/AngleBracket[x^2]+Sum[v'[y[j]],j];
term //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{x \left\langle x \left(\sum _j v'(y(j))-x\right)\right\rangle }{\left\langle
>    x^2\right\rangle }+\sum _j v'(y(j))$

and want to apply `Expand` only to the part within the AngleBrackets. How can I do that?

The result for this simple example is supposed to be

```
(x AngleBracket[-x^2 + x Sum[v'[y[j]],j]])/AngleBracket[x^2] + Sum[v'[y[j]],j] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{x \left\langle x \sum _j v'(y(j))-x^2\right\rangle }{\left\langle x^2\right\rangle
>    }+\sum _j v'(y(j))$

It is important to me that a solution should work for any example, no matter the depth of the expression etc.

Comment: does `Replace[expr,  AngleBracket[a_] :> AngleBracket[Expand[a]],All]` give what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I like using [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition) (@*) for this kind of thing:

```
term /. AngleBracket -> AngleBracket @* Expand //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{x \left\langle x \sum _j v'(y(j))-x^2\right\rangle }{\left\langle x^2\right\rangle
>    }+\sum _j v'(y(j))$